# Client server with Rabbit Message Queue

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

I am trying to write a basic client server communication using Rabbit message Queue. 
I achieved that by declaring the exact same queue in both client and server.

The problem is that now I get all the messages in both sides.

Server messages are also received in the server and client messages are also received in the client.

How can I achieve separation - make server receive only messages from client, and make client receive only messages from server?

Should I create 2 different queues for this? Or is there a way to filter the messages somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you really need it like this, then 2 queues. Possibly headers exchange and then "tag" the receiver in the header of the message...

Take a look at [RPC tutorial from rabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-dotnet.html), sounds like this is what you're after

Comment: Would it be a good approach to keep an xml configuration file with the queues for each side? It isn't necessarily that only the client sends requests to the server as presented in the rpc example. There is also a case of push notifications from the server to the client.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with xml config file with queues, but in general - no, queue names are kinda worthless. You are always consuming from exchange. So if you have one exchange, and use two different routing keys, then have one consumer (server or client in your case) declare a queue with first routing key, and the other consumer with second

Comment: maybe a typo but `You are always consuming from exchange` is not correct, You always consuming from a queue, never from an exchange.

Comment: @Gabriele exactly, sorry and thx! So we're always publishing to an exchange and consuming from a queue.